# Why my terminal throws control characters while using arrows in mysql-client?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, mysql

I have a situation with remote servers (all Debians) where I get control chars into `mysql-client` command line when I try to search in history (<kbd>CTR</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and try to make the first move:

```
mysql> update r_isik set originaal = 'inglise' [Cwhere tolkija = 'j' and r_nr = 292140;
```

I was searching `wh` and then stroked the right arrow to edit the command. Instead of selecting the line and moving one char, my terminal throws `[C` into line. Next moves with arrows work fine.

I have servers, where it works fine (without throwing the garbage) and others that don't and I don't find the difference in settings.

What is the cause of showing control chars on the screen instead of sending corresponding moving instructions?

All connections are made with the same terminal app over the ssh.

Comment: The same which terminal app?

Comment: @Destroy666 Actually different ones: Gnome Terminal, Konsole, Windows Terminal

Comment: Right arrow is transmitted as `^[[C`, where `^[` denotes a single byte, the escape character (octal `033`). The problem is as if something consumed this byte, but not always. Or *maybe* `mysql-client` requires the whole `^[[C` sequence to arrive without much delay, but for some reason sometimes there is a delay between `^[` and `[`. I do not know the tool. To check, get to the point when the right arrow works fine, press Ctrl+`[`, wait several seconds, type `[C`. Does it behave like right arrow even then? If so, then it's not about delay.

Comment: What keys do you press _exactly_? Do you by any chance press the Esc key?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski pressing  `^[` clears the command line (in mysql-client) or from the cursor to the beginning of the line (in bash).

Comment: @egmont I press `CTR+r`, release it, type the search string `wh`, and press the arrow key to the right. No escapes involved.